# select from db link inside package body

Tags: oracle, package, database-link

When creating a package body i cannot have a select from another db link inside the package body? I dont know the value of the dblink name from before therefore

```
Create or replace package body sth as 
 procedure getvalues(linkname in char)
 is
 begin
 select col1 from table1@linkname;
end getvalues;
end sth;
```

When i create this i get that table or view does not exist.. The link name i dont know it from before hand its in parameter which will be used as:

```
getvalues(linkname => dbname);
```

How can you have these values inside the package body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the name of the database link at compile time, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  Regardless of whether you're using dynamic SQL or static SQL, though, a procedure can't just run a SQL statement.  It would have to do something with the results.  You could open a `sys_refcursor` either as a local variable or as an `OUT` parameter.  You could iterate through the results, fetching the data and doing something with the results.  The fact that you have declared a procedure rather than a function implies that you want to modify the database state somehow rather than simply returning a `sys_refcursor`.  But the name of the procedure implies that maybe you really want a function that returns a `sys_refcursor`.

If you really want a function that returns a `sys_refcursor`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getValues( p_dblink IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc FOR 'SELECT col1 FROM table1@' || p_dblink;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```